# Assign a header to multiple files, Linux

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, cat

A `header` file is produced by running the main script and its content changes anytime I run the program . I want to assign the content of header file to other three files as their header. The content of other three files should not change except their header. For example for `file1`

```
header content
file1 content
```

for `file2`

```
header content
file2 content
```

How it is done?

Note: Please consider that the program runs many times so the header must be overwritten not many headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this code once to preserve the original files without the header information:

```
for file in myfile1 myfile2 myfile3
do
  cp ${file} ${file}.orig
done
```

run this code every time your header file changes

```
for file in myfile1 myfile2 myfile3
do
  cat header ${file}.orig > ${file}
done
```

where myfile1, myfile2 and myfile3 are the 3 original files you were referring and header is the file containing the ever changing header information.

Comment: running the program second time file with header is copied to  file.orig (cp ${file} ${file}.orig) Then I have two headers.

Comment: @newzad - Answer contains two programs. The first one must be run only once.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

This code will backup each $file if it hasn't been saved before and then join the header on to the saved body. Just make sure the files don't have the header on the first time you run the script.

```
for file in myfile{1,2,3}
do
    [ -f $file.body ] || mv $file $file.body
    cat header $file.body >$file
done
```

Comment: I did for just one file. It works well, header does not accumulate in the files with every run. However there are always 3 headers in a file. I just used: [ -f file1.body ] || mv file1 file1.body
       cat header file1.body >file1

Comment: @newzad As I said, make sure the file starts with no headers before you run the script.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` should do it

```
cat header file1 > file1-t
mv file1-t file1
```

Comment: I did something similar to this, but when file1 used second time it has two header.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cat headerfile file1 > file1_withHeader
```

Comment: better to do with cat instead